# So I can't have NOT NULL in column definition of temporal tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, temporal

I am using SQL Server 2016 and trying to create Temporal table. Here is the definition:

```
USE zbachoreTest
GO`enter code here`
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'People' AND temporal_type_desc ='SYSTEM_VERSIONED_TEMPORAL_TABLE' )
ALTER TABLE dbo.People SET( SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF)
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.People 
CREATE TABLE dbo.People(
    PersonID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_People PRIMARY KEY(PersonID),
    FirstName VARCHAR(50) NOT  NULL,
    LastName VARCHAR(50)  NULL,
    StartTime DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT DF_People_StartTime DEFAULT SYSDATETIME(),
    EndTime DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT DF_People_EndTime DEFAULT CONVERT(DATETIME2,'9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999'),
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME(StartTime,EndTime)
    ) WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.PeopleHistory))
```

when I run the above code, I am getting the following error message:
Msg 13531, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Setting SYSTEM_VERSIONING to ON failed because column 'FirstName' does not have the same nullability attribute in tables 'zbachoreTest.dbo.People' and 'zbachoreTest.dbo.PeopleHistory'.

Any smart folks out there please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Do `drop table dbo.PeopleHistory` first. If it already exists, it will be only validated, not recreated.

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/creating-a-system-versioned-temporal-table

> The history table must always be schema-aligned with the current or
>   temporal table, in terms of number of columns, column names, ordering
>   and data types.

and

> If the table specified by the HISTORY_TABLE parameter already exists,
>   it will be validated against the newly created temporal table in terms
>   of schema consistency and temporal data consistency. If you specify an
>   invalid history table, the CREATE TABLE statement will fail.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now that you explained, it makes perfect sense!